# Arranging a string in uppercase-first alphabetical order C++

Tags: c++, string, sorting

I was trying to create a program in C++ that sorts a given string in alphabetical order in a way where the uppercase letters precede their lowercase equivalent.
Example:
DCBAdcba
Sorted string:
AaBbCcDd

Given below is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
struct char_ {
    char c;
    char diff;
    char_();
    char_(char x);
};
char_::char_() {
    c = 0;
    diff = 0;
}
char_::char_(char x) {
    c = std::tolower(x);
    diff = c - x;
}

void charswap(char_& x, char_& y) {
    char_ temp;
    temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

int main() {
    std::string str;
    getline(std::cin, str);
    char_* str2 = new char_[str.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        str2[i] = char_(str[i]);
    }

    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        std::cout << str2[i].c << std::endl;
    }
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < str.length(); j++) {
            if (str2[i].c > str2[j].c)
                charswap(str2[i], str2[j]);
        }
    }


    for (int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++) {
    std::cout << str2[k].c << "\t" << (int)str2[k].diff << std::endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

    str2[i].c = str2[i].c - str2[i].diff;
    }




    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) std::cout << str2[i].c;
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

A char_ struct is created to store the individual characters(converted to to lowercase) and their difference from the uppercase equivalent(0 or 32, depending if the original char was lowercase or uppercase, respectively). It then sorts the char_ characters on the basis of their lowercase values. And after the sort we add back the difference to the character to retrieve the uppercase form.

But when I try giving this string, it gives the following result.

DCBAdcba

AabBCcdD

I cannot understand what's happening here.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: You created a case-insensitive sort algorithm. I see no code to give capitals priority.

Comment: Hint - search for 'Ascii table' and note the values assigned to each character.

Comment: @UKMonkey C++ does not have to use ASCII

Comment: EBCDIC shall return!

Comment: @NathanOliver no, it doesn't.  Do you think that it is in this case though?

Comment: @UKMonkey It might be but why limit your code?  Using magic numbers is generally a error in code.

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't say anything about using it in his code, I was pointing it out so that he can understand why they're not in the expected order.

Comment: @NathanOliver , what do you mean by C++ does not have to use ASCII?

Comment: @shiladityabasu C++ was designed to work with multiple different character sets.  One, [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), is completely different from ASCII meaning if the use `48` in your code instead of `'0'` in a EBCDIC environment you would actually have blank character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
if (str2[i].c > str2[j].c)
    charswap(str2[i], str2[j]);
```

It compares characters in case-insensitive way, with no provision for tie breaking when lowercase characters are the same.

You need to modify this to swap characters when lowercase on the right is greater than lowercase on the left, or when lowercase representations are the same, but the right side original character is in upper case:

```
if ((str2[i].c > str2[j].c) || (str2[i].c == str2[j].c && str2[j].diff))
    charswap(str2[i], str2[j]);
```

Answer (score 4):

> sorts a given string in alphabetical order in a way where the uppercase letters precede their lowercase equivalent.

You can just define a comparison functor reflecting your intention

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct case_cmp {
    bool operator()(char lhs, char rhs) const {
        return (std::isupper(lhs) && std::tolower(lhs) == rhs) || std::tolower(lhs) < std::tolower(rhs);
    }
};
```

Then use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
int main() {
    std::string s("DCBAdcba");
    std::sort(std::begin(s), std::end(s), case_cmp());
    // Outputs "AaBbCcDd"
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` can be considered as a **container** of `char`s, and as such you can apply STL's *algorithms* to its content, including `std::sort()` (just like you would apply an STL algorithm to e.g. `std::vector`).

You can specify your particular *custom sorting criteria* using a *lambda*, to be passed as the third parameter to `std::sort()`, e.g. ([**live on Ideone**](http://ideone.com/OlYfJZ)):

```
#include <algorithm>    // for std::sort
#include <cctype>       // for std::isupper, std::tolower
#include <iostream>     // for std::cout
#include <string>       // for std::string
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s{"DCBAdcba"};

    sort( s.begin(), s.end(), [](char x, char y) { 
        // Custom sorting criteria.
        // Return true if x precedes y.

        // This may work, but requires more testing...
        if (isupper(x)) {
            if (tolower(x) == y) {
                return true;    
            }   
        }
        return tolower(x) < tolower(y);
    });

    cout << s << '\n';
}
```